# Как вывести стикер "новинки" на картинку в Bitrix

Tags: javascript, битрикс, cms

как вывести текст/картинку в каталоге, пробовал всеми способами, которые есть в гугле, но похоже я не до конца вдупляю
NEW - это переменная в инф.блоке
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdcuF.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCaUG.png

```
<?if ($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["NEW"]["VALUE"] === "Y"):?> // Не работает, пример из интернета, стоит чекбокс, предполагаю, что работает N - не стоит галка, Y - стоит галка
<p> Новинка </p>
<?endif;?>

<?if($item['PREVIEW_PICTURE']):?>
<img src="<?=$item['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']?>" alt="" loading="lazy" />
<?endif?>
```

Comment: Скорее всего, нужно использовать не $arResult, а $item. Вам же нужно проверять свойство у каждого элемента.

Comment: Не дало никакого к сожалению результата